# Capitalize all first letters in a table except for the last row using CSS

Tags: html, css

The below CSS code capitalizes every first letter of the first row in the table. However, I don't want the very last row to be have its first letter capitalized. I have tried using the `:not()` selector with no success. Any idea's?

```
table tr td:first-child::first-letter {
    font-size:30px; 
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `:not(:last-child)` on the `tr`:

```css
table tr:not(:last-child) td:first-child::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>ab</td><td>cd</td><td>ef</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab</td><td>cd</td><td>ef</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab</td><td>cd</td><td>ef</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the css directive text-transform setted capitalize

so your css will be

```
table tr td:first-letter{
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

to avoid that last row will be affected you can use the pseudo selector :last-child

```
table tr:last-child td:first-letter{
 text-transform:none;
}
```