# capitalize first word of sentence in html specific table

Tags: html, css

I have table headings in html webpage (Like ID(1)  Symbol(AAPL) Name(APPLE INCORPORATION)) all names are in uppercases. I want only the first word to be capital (Like Apple Incorporation).
Any help!

```
Table Headings:  ID Symbol Name
Table Data rows: 1  AAPL   Apple Incorporation

<html>
    <head>
        <title>stocks</title>
        <link
```

rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semanticui@2.4.2/distsemantic.min.css">

## Stock List

ID
Symbol
Name
Exchange
Country



{% for stock in stocks %}

{{ stock.security_id }}
{{ stock.ticker }}
[{{ stock.full_name }}](/stock/%7B%7B%20%0Astock.exchange%20%0A%7D%7D/%7B%7B%20stock.ticker%20%7D%7D)
{{stock.exchange }}
{{stock.country }}

{% endfor %}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalize all first letters in a table except for the last row using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191598/capitalize-all-first-letters-in-a-table-except-for-the-last-row-using-css)

Comment: the link mention above and your Question Deals with same logic thus its an duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-transform: capitalize;`

```css
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<h2>text-transform: capitalize:</h2>
<div class="capitalize">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css property text-transform to the text

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Answer (score -1):

**please follow the example**

```css
p.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<p class="capitalize">This is some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```